# Hide item in TabBarController [xcode6/swift]

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a TabBarController that is linked to 4 ViewControllers, so the tab bar displays 4 items, but I only want to display 3 items.

How to I hide the other tab bar item?

I want that the ViewController that is no displayed on the tab bar also displays the tab bar.

Here is the story board:

[image: Story Board]

And here is the app on the simulator:

[image: Simulator]

I want the "Notificaciones" item to be hidden (it is the initial view that is displayed)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `UITabBarItem` with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[tabBarViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers: tabBarViewControllers animated:YES];
```

It looks like the way you have this setup right now, that once you select one of the other views, you will not be able to return to the Notificaciones view without reloading the whole UITabBarViewController.

Comment: Where do I have to put this code? Do you know how to do it in swift?

Comment: I've already figure it out how to do it in swift, and the tab bar button is removed, but also the corresponding view. I just want the button to be gone, not the view. Any ideas?